# Why does deno's exec package execute commands without outputting messages to the terminal?

Tags: deno

```js
import { exec } from "https://deno.land/x/exec/mod.ts";

await exec(`git clone https://github.com/vuejs/vue.git`)
```

when i use `git clone https://github.com/vuejs/vue.git` in .sh file, It has message in terminal,
but don't have in deno

Comment: The `exec` module is not related to Deno. All modules at `https://deno.land/x/...` are third-party code. For working with your shell, see [Creating a subprocess](https://deno.land/manual@v1.13.2/examples/subprocess) in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think it is important to echo what [jsejcksn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438273/jsejcksn) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068364/why-does-denos-exec-package-execute-commands-without-outputting-messages-to-the#comment122072299_69068364):

> The `exec` module is not related to Deno. All modules at `https://deno.land/x/...` are third-party code. For working with your shell, see [Creating a subprocess in the manual](https://deno.land/manual@v1.13.2/examples/subprocess).

Deno's way of doing this without a 3rd party library is to use `Deno.run`.

With that said, if you take a look at `exec`'s README you'll find documentation for what you're looking for under [Capture the output of an external command](https://deno.land/x/exec@0.0.5#capture-the-output-of-an-external-command):

> Sometimes you need to capture the output of a command. For example, I do this to get git log checksums:
>
> ```
> import { exec } from "https://deno.land/x/exec/mod.ts";
> let response = await exec('git log -1 --format=%H', {output: OutputMode.Capture});
> ```

If you look at `exec`'s code you'll find it uses `Deno.run` under the hoods. If you like `exec` you can use it but you might find you like using `Deno.run` directly instead.